# Get subject new mails from a office365 mail account

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to download the subject of all new mails. The mails are stored in an office365 mail account. So far i have the following:

```
<cfimap 
      action ="OPEN"     
      connection = "Test" 
      password = "xxxx" 
      port = "993" 
      secure = "yes"  
      server = "outlook.office365.com" 
      stoponerror = "true" 
      timeout = "10" 
      username = "xxxx">    

<cfimap 
  action="getHeaderOnly" 
    folder="Inbox"  
  connection="Test" 
  name="getHeaders"
>

<Cfdump var=#getHeaders#>
<cfimap action="close" connection = "Test">
```

This is ridiculously slow (several minutes). In my situation I only need to download the subject line of all new mails. I do not need anything else. Any thoughts on how to speed up things.

**Update**
Came up with an alternative solution. See [Convert java code to coldfusion code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48770219/2482184) for an alternative to the cfimap tag.

Comment: What's the slow part?

Comment: <cfimap action="getHeaderOnly" folder="Inbox" connection="Test" name="getHeaders"> is very slow. .

Comment: how many emails in the inbox?

Comment: There can be many mails in the mailbox (100+). But even with only 10 mails cfimap is very slow.